# rsync --compare-dest does not work

Tags: rsync

I have these directories `SRC`, `DST`, `COMPARE`:

- `/opt/SRC`

  ```
  file1
  file2
  file3
  ```
- `/opt/DST`

  ```
  file1
  file2
  ```
- `/opt/COMPARE`

  *empty*

I wish:

```
$ ls /opt/COMPARE
file3
```

But when I run :

```
rsync -avz --compare-dest=/opt/COMPARE /opt/SRC/ /opt/DST
```

The `/opt/COMPARE` directory is still empty, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are applying the `--compare-dest` incorrectly.

From `man rsync`

> ```
>    --compare-dest=DIR
>           This option instructs rsync to use DIR on the destination machine as an  additional
>           hierarchy  to  compare  destination files against doing transfers (if the files are
>           missing in the destination directory).  If a file is found in DIR that is identical
>           to  the  sender’s  file, the file will NOT be transferred to the destination direc‐
>           tory.  This is useful for creating a sparse backup of just files that have  changed
>           from  an  earlier  backup.  This option is typically used to copy into an empty (or
>           newly created) directory.
>
>          Beginning in version 2.6.4, multiple --compare-dest directories  may  be  provided,
>           which  will  cause  rsync  to  search  the list in the order specified for an exact
>           match.  If a match is found that differs only in attributes, a local copy  is  made
>           and  the attributes updated.  If a match is not found, a basis file from one of the
>           DIRs will be selected to try to speed up the transfer.
>
>          If DIR is a relative path, it is relative to the destination directory.   See  also
>           --copy-dest and --link-dest.
>
>          NOTE:  beginning with version 3.1.0, rsync will remove a file from a non-empty des‐
>           tination hierarchy if an exact match is found in one of  the  compare-dest  hierar‐
>           chies (making the end result more closely match a fresh copy).
> ```

If I am reading this correctly, `--compare-dest` used used to **stop** the sending certain files.  This would allow you to create a new copy destination directory, containing only files that have changed since the last copy.  Sort of an incremental copy, if you will.

Answer (score 0):

1. rsync will compare the files in /opt/SRC to the files in /opt/COMPARE.  If file exists in /opt/SRC and doesn't exist in /opt/COMPARE, or different version of it exists in both, it will copy it to /opt/DST.
2. rsync is not only inspecting content when deciding if files are "identical". For this to work correctly, you should sometimes use flags like "--no-times" (this oneworked for me in one occasion), or "--no-perms", "--no-owner", "--no-group, "--checksum", etc.
3. it is a good idea to use "--dry-run" to test the behavior, without actually copy.